# How to get state from the store and pass to a new component?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

ok i am fairly new to React-native and redux so please keep it simple for me. i did some research and read over may of the redux docs but perhaps i am not looking for the correct information.

first i create a plan.

```
class PlanCreate extends Component {
   onButtonPress() {
       const {title, city, district} = this.props;

       this.props.planCreate({title, city, district});
   }
    render () {
      return (
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Input
              lable="Title"
              placeholder="New Plan"
              autoCorrect={false}
              value={this.props.title}
              onChangeText={value => this.props.planUpdate({prop: 'title', value})}
            />
          </CardSection>
          <CardSection>
            <Input
              lable="City"
              placeholder="Oakland"
              autoCorrect={true}
              value={this.props.city}
              onChangeText={value => this.props.planUpdate({prop: 'city', value})}
            />
          </CardSection>
           <CardSection>
            <Input
              lable="District"
              placeholder="Chinatown"
              autoCorrect={true}
              value={this.props.district}
              onChangeText={value => this.props.planUpdate({prop: 'district', value})}
            />
          </CardSection>

          <CardSection>
            <Button onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}>
              Create Plan
            </Button>
          </CardSection>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
  const styles = {
    pickerTextStyle: {
      fontSize: 18,
      paddingLeft: 20
    }
  };
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {title, city, district} = state.planForm;
    return {title, city, district}
  };
  export default  connect(mapStateToProps, {planUpdate, planCreate})(PlanCreate);
```

then send it off to my rails backend server

```
export const planCreate = ({ title, city, district}) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
      var user_id = 1;
       axios.post('http://localhost:3000/plans', { params: { user_id: user_id, title: title, city: city, district: district}
      }).then((response) => {
        dispatch({ type: PLAN_CREATE, payload: response.data});
       Actions.plan();
      });
    };
```

then i update my state with the new plan_id form the server.

```
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {

switch (action.type) {
  case PLAN_UPDATE:
    return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value};
  case PLAN_CREATE:
    return { ...state, plan_id:  action.payload.id};
  default:
    return state;
  }
};
```

After this i navigate to a new page, from there i need to grab that newly assigned plan_id out of the state and reference it in a new post request to my server from the new page.

Comment: anywhere you need to access the state, you need to either wrap the component in connect and provide the mapStateToProp function or access the store directly through `context` and the `store.getState` method. begin `connect` always the recommended choice